# Clang++/g++ not vectorizing code on Aarch64

Tags: c++, arm, neon

I have a SBC with quad-core Cortex-A57 and am trying to experiment with Neon using compiler auto-vectorization. With both clang++ (5.0.1-4) and g++ (7.4.0) on Ubuntu 18.04, the very simple code below is not vectorized (i.e., it doesn't employ the v registers at any point):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

int main(void)
    {
    const uint32_t  LEN = 16;
    float           input_1[LEN] __attribute__((__aligned__(16))),
                    input_2[LEN] __attribute__((__aligned__(16))),
                    output [LEN] __attribute__((__aligned__(16)));

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        {
        input_1[i] = i;
        input_2[i] = i * 2;
        }

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        output[i] = input_1[i] * input_2[i];

    std::cout << output[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

It just declares 3 arrays, populates 2 and multiplies them on the output array. The cout at the end is to prevent the compiler from getting rid of everything. I didn't post the result of objdump -d to avoid spamming people's screen, but I can if someone wants. The compilation line is: clang++ -O3 neon.cpp -o neon (the same for g++)

I have also tried with -mcpu=cortex-a57 but it won't vectorize either. Then I found this post https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65951

Comment 11 says that depending on the situation, the compiler may decide not to vectorize if there is not a performance advantage. From your experience,  does it seem to be the case, or am I missing something?

**====== EDIT ======**

The assembly produced by g++ for the above code is:

```
    .arch armv8-a
    .file   "neon_test.cpp"
    .text
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .align  2
    .p2align 3,,7
    .global main
    .type   main, %function
main:
.LFB1563:
    .cfi_startproc
    stp x29, x30, [sp, -112]!
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 112
    .cfi_offset 29, -112
    .cfi_offset 30, -104
    adrp    x1, .LC0
    adrp    x0, :got:_ZSt4cout
    movi    d0, #0
    add x29, sp, 0
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 29
    str x19, [sp, 16]
    .cfi_offset 19, -96
    adrp    x19, :got:__stack_chk_guard
    ldr q1, [x1, #:lo12:.LC0]
    ldr x19, [x19, #:got_lo12:__stack_chk_guard]
    ldr x0, [x0, #:got_lo12:_ZSt4cout]
    ldr x1, [x19]
    str x1, [x29, 104]
    mov x1,0
    str q1, [x29, 32]
    bl  _ZNSo9_M_insertIdEERSoT_
    bl  _ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_
    ldr x0, [x29, 104]
    ldr x1, [x19]
    eor x1, x0, x1
    cbnz    x1, .L5
    ldr x19, [sp, 16]
    mov w0, 0
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 112
    .cfi_remember_state
    .cfi_restore 30
    .cfi_restore 29
    .cfi_restore 19
    .cfi_def_cfa 31, 0
    ret
.L5:
    .cfi_restore_state
    bl  __stack_chk_fail
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1563:
    .size   main, .-main
    .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .align  4
.LC0:
    .word   0
    .word   1073741824
    .word   1090519040
    .word   1099956224
    .section    .text.startup
    .align  2
    .p2align 3,,7
    .type   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, %function
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
.LFB2050:
    .cfi_startproc
    stp x29, x30, [sp, -32]!
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
    .cfi_offset 29, -32
    .cfi_offset 30, -24
    add x29, sp, 0
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 29
    str x19, [sp, 16]
    .cfi_offset 19, -16
    adrp    x19, .LANCHOR0
    add x19, x19, :lo12:.LANCHOR0
    mov x0, x19
    bl  _ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
    adrp    x0, :got:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
    mov x1, x19
    ldr x19, [sp, 16]
    adrp    x2, __dso_handle
    ldr x0, [x0, #:got_lo12:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev]
    add x2, x2, :lo12:__dso_handle
    ldp x29, x30, [sp], 32
    .cfi_restore 30
    .cfi_restore 29
    .cfi_restore 19
    .cfi_def_cfa 31, 0
    b   __cxa_atexit
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE2050:
    .size   _GLOBAL__sub_I_main, .-_GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .section    .init_array,"aw"
    .align  3
    .xword  _GLOBAL__sub_I_main
    .bss
    .align  3
    .set    .LANCHOR0,. + 0
    .type   _ZStL8__ioinit, %object
    .size   _ZStL8__ioinit, 1
_ZStL8__ioinit:
    .zero   1
    .hidden __dso_handle
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Comment: It looks to be vectorized here: https://godbolt.org/z/zNWTz_

Comment: From what I read so far, the compilers first evaluate the cost of vectorization and then may decide to generate scalar code if the overhead doesn't bring any benefits. It could be that this tool doesn't evaluate this situation.

Comment: Godbolt is using GCC.  The link I posted is for what GCC 7.4 with -O3 produces.  Can you post the assembly that you get?

Comment: Done. Notice that there are 128 bits load/store with register q1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generate the inputs in the same function that does the actual math.

Q: What does the compiler do under `-o3` then?

A: It does the math in build time, and stores the results in sort of LUT. (`.LC0`)

You should initialize the inputs in an external function, preferably in a different file in order to avoid this kind of "build time math" cheating by compilers.

0 = 0.0f = 0.0f * 2.0f * 0.0f
1073741824 = 2.0f = 1.0f * 2.0f * 1.0f
1090519040 = 8.0f = 2.0f * 2.0f * 2.0f
1099956224 = 18.0f = 3.0f * 2.0f * 3.0f

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it as soon as I have the computer in front of me.

Comment: Spot on. As soon as I moved the population of input arrays to a function (in the same file), g++ vectorized the code. Thanks to all.